# PyCharm break on exception does not work with Theano

Tags: python, exception, pycharm, pydev, theano

I cannot get PyCharm to stop on the line of code where an exception is raised, when I import Theano.

My code:

```
import theano
raise Exception()
```

I expect PyCharm debugger to stop on the `raise Exception()` line, but it throws a `RuntimeError` and exits the debugger:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 89, in _excepthook
    _original_excepthook(exctype, value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 58, in thunk_hook
    __excepthook(type, value, trace)
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 89, in _excepthook
    _original_excepthook(exctype, value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 58, in thunk_hook
    __excepthook(type, value, trace)
  <...>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 58, in thunk_hook
    __excepthook(type, value, trace)
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 84, in _excepthook
    exception_breakpoint = get_exception_breakpoint(exctype, _handle_exceptions)
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 65, in get_exception_breakpoint
    exception_full_qname = get_exception_full_qname(exctype)
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 53, in get_exception_full_qname
    def get_exception_full_qname(exctype):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2357, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/homes/user/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1777, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/homes/user/corp/python/projects/n_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

Comment: In general, `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` happens when the python global interpreter recurses compiled theano code more than it is allowed.  Why it happens on import, I don't know, but you can set the maximum depth to some larger (1e6) number and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Try update pip. I had the same error before I do `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip` . I used `sudo -H` because it's on OSX 10.11.2.

Answer (score 0):

One hack is to comment out this line `sys.excepthook = thunk_hook` in `.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py`

Comment: Unless it's a bug or a missing feature, patching library code isn't a real solution.

Comment: This does sound like a bug though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in one of the libs (maybe both :^)).

For some reason, `theano`'s and `PyCharm`'s excepthooks both think of the other one as its ancestor.

Add debug printing into both libs at points where `sys.excepthook` and member variables that point to the previous handler are set to reveal the setting order. Someone appears to be breaking the handler chaining rules.